# does puppet agent support python and python module installation on Windows platform?

Tags: python-2.7, puppet

does puppet agent support python and python module installation on Windows platform?

I found this third party module which it claims could install python module on Windows: https://github.com/counsyl/puppet-python

Wondering if it's necessary ?

Comment: If a provider is installed then yes.

Comment: The core Puppet distribution does not have *specific* support for Python installation, but inasmuch as Puppet can manage just about anything, you indeed can teach it to manage Python installations.  Using a module such as the one you reference would save you some time and effort in that regard.  Given Python itself installed on the target system, Puppet *does* come with built-in support for installing Python modules via `pip` or `pip3`, or via general-purpose packaging systems such as MSI.